Need help finding old movie where Cleopatra / Goddess / Queen makes man sacrifice himself for her
I saw a film when I was a kid (either between 1998 -2002) it was an old movie then possibly in black and white, or just the old colour style movie that looks a bit washed out. 
It was shown on UK TV. Think it was about Cleopatra or a Goddess like her. The scene I recall she orders a man to dive off a ledge or a cliff to sacrifice himself for her. Think he may have jumped into some kind of fire pit. The man wasn't pushed he proudly obeyed and dived off. 
Unfortunately I cannot remember anything more about it. 
Edit: I can only assume it would have been in English. I believe the man may have got down on his knees for the woman, and he then stood on some kind of platform cliff or ledge and dived off. He was of muscular build and was not wearing much, either under pants or some kind of loin cloth. I have watched both versions of the film "She" and also the sequel and the scene I am recalling was not in any of these movies,

Hi and welcome to M&TV! This scene is a bit generic, so are you sure you can't remember any other scenes or plot points, however vaguely? The actress (or actors) and what they looked like? Was it in English?

Hey thank you! I have racked my brain, I can only assume it would have been in English as it probably would have been turned off otherwise. This is the only scene of the film I can recall at all (as I was a kid I think it was just on in the background but that scene intrigued me and I want to discover it) I believe the man may have got down on his knees for the woman, and he then stood on some kind of platform cliff or ledge and dived off. He was of muscular build and was not wearing much either under pants or some kind of loin cloth. I know this is incredibly vague and I appreciate all help

Maybe one of the Allan Quatermain films - King Solomon's Treasure perhaps.

Almost certainly She (1965) which was a staple for UK television.


After receiving honorable discharges from the British Army in Palestine in 1918, Professor Holly (Peter Cushing), young Leo Vincey (John Richardson) and their orderly Job (Bernard Cribbins) embark on an expedition into a previously unexplored region of north-east Africa. They discover the lost city of Kuma after Leo receives a mysterious map revealing the city's whereabouts.
This lost realm is ruled by Ayesha (Ursula Andress), who is also known as "She-Who-Waits" and "She-Who-Must-Be-Obeyed." Ayesha is an immortal queen and high priestess who believes Leo is the reincarnation of her former lover, the priest Kallikrates (whom she killed when she found him in an intimate embrace with another woman about two thousand years before). Ayesha tries to convince Leo to walk into a bonfire after it has turned blue, which happens once certain astronomical conditions have occurred. It will only remain in this condition for a short period and only happens on certain rare occasions. By entering the fire, Leo himself will become immortal.
Wikipdia

There's a scene where people are thrown into a firepit.




Hey Paulie_D thanks for that a great suggestion, but I watched this last night, and it wasn't what I remembered seeing. I should have put that in my initial question. The scene where he jumps into the fire pit in the film I'm thinking of just seems really civilised like he is pleased to do it for her. Great suggestion though it does seem very similar, I will  edit my question.
